# multiple azure app settings from multiple json files

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-cli

I have a resource group I have many json configs and multiple webjobs and functions

what i want is that we just update the json file and put the name of that azure webapp and the configurations should be loaded from that json file and added in app settings

can some one help to achieve it with either powershell or bash script

Answer (score 0):

We have `Update-AzFunctionAppSetting` to add or update the app settings in a function app.

> update the json file and put the name of that azure webapp and the configurations should be loaded from that json file and added in app settings

To add your app name into the app settings, use this syntax of PowerShell Script:

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting
      -Name <String>
      -ResourceGroupName <String>
      -AppSetting <Hashtable>
      [-SubscriptionId <String>]
      [-Force]
      [-DefaultProfile <PSObject>]
      [-Confirm]
      [-WhatIf]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

***Example to add a new app setting in a function app:***

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -AppSetting @{"Name1" = "Value1"}
```

For more details on these script objects and parameters included in adding or updating the app settings in json file using powershell script, refer this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.functions/update-azfunctionappsetting?view=azps-6.6.0).